# How can I write long numbers to the var in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a constant with 8 zeros. How write it in var with good readability?

java way:

```
int number = 100_000_000;
```

Have PHP something similar?

Comment: Is it good readability?

Comment: Is it not? What do you mean by good readability? It says that `$var` is equal to `100000000`. Is that not readable enough?

Comment: What do you define as "good readability" ?

Comment: how many zeros you wrote? 8, 9 ?

Comment: Why downvote the question ? PHP's popular contributors has think about it. The question is simple, there is no clear answer available on the web. It worth asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the way you expose it.
Recently a RFC (request for comments) has been proposed to address a solution to this, but this proposal has been rejected. See https://wiki.php.net/rfc/number_format_separator

However you still can write it this way : `$var = 10e7;`